# How to do command line comparison?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am trying to use the following set of commands

```
FOR /f %%B IN ('DIR %SOME_FOLDER_LOCATION%\*.html ^| FIND "File(s)"') DO SET cnt=%%B
ECHO %cnt%
```

and

```
TYPE %SOME_TEXT_FILE_PATH% | FIND /V /C "abcxyzabczyx"
```

After this i need to compare the output from both the lines and based on that display some status something like:

```
IF [%cnt%]==['TYPE %SOME_TEXT_FILE_PATH% | FIND /V /C "xyzxyzxyzxyz"'] ECHO CORRECT
```

The second portion of comparison is repetition. Wrote it just to give you an idea.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of .html files, I would use this method:

```
SET cnt=0
FOR %%B IN (%SOME_FOLDER_LOCATION%\*.html) DO SET /A cnt=cnt+1
ECHO %cnt%
```

To count the number of finds, I would use this:

```
FOR /f %%B IN ('FIND /V /C "abcxyzabczyx" %SOME_TEXT_FILE_PATH%') DO SET finds=%%B
```

This way, to compare both numbers:

```
IF [%cnt%] == [%finds%] ECHO CORRECT
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: The value of 'finds' is not getting set accordingly. Its displaying as ----------

Comment: Oops, my mistake! Just insert a `<` before the file name in FIND command: `FIND /V /C "abcxyzabczyx" < %SOME_TEXT_FILE_PATH%`.

Answer (score 1):

Do the first one twice with your different command lines, but set a different variable too. Then just compare the two variables.